# Row in Excel to array?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, python-2.7, csv

I have lots of data in an Excel spreadsheet that I need to import using Python. i need each row to be read as an array so I can call on the first data point in a specified row, the second, the third, and so on.

This is my code so far:

```
from array import *
import csv

with open ('vals.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    reader_x = []
    reader_y = []
    reader_z = []
    row = next(reader)
    reader_x.append(row)
    row = next(reader)
    reader_y.append(row)
    row = next(reader)
    reader_z.append(row)

    print reader_x
    print reader_y
    print reader_z

    print reader_x[0]
```

It is definitely storing it as an array I think. But I think it is storing the entire row of Excel as a string instead of each block being a separate data point, because when I tell Python to print an entire array it looks something like this (a shortened version because there's like a thousand in each row):

```
[['13,14,12']]
```

And when I tell it to `print reader_x[0]` (or any of the other two for that matter) it looks like this:

```
['13,14,12']
```

But when I tell it to print anything beyond the 0th thing in the array, it just gives me an error because it's out of range.

How can I fix this? How can I make it `[13,14,12]` instead of `['13,14,12']` so I can actually use these numbers in calculation? (I want to avoid downloading any more libraries if I can because this is for a school thing and I need to avoid that if possible.)

I have been stuck on this for several days and nothing I can find has worked for me and half of it I didn't even understand. Please try to explain simply if you can, as if you're talking to someone who doesn't even know how to `print "Hello World"`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a few rows from the beginning of the Excel csv file in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to do this and use `,` as a separator.

For example:

```
row = '11,12,13'
row = row.split(',')
```

Comment: i tried this but I got this error

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Try splitting a string, not a list. Anyway, just let the `csv` module do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a csv, (comma separated values) try setting delimiter to ','

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `from array import *` ... What the rest of the world calls an array is called a `list` in Python. The Python `array` is rather specialised and you are not actually using it so just delete that line of code.

As others have pointed out, you need incoming lines to be split. The `csv` default delimiter is a comma. Just let csv.reader do the job, something like this:

```
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
data = [map(int, row) for row in reader]
```

Comment: thank!!!! i finally got it to work and give me individual values! thank you so much!!!